# Convert multidimensional array dimension in Python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

Is it possible to convert this:

```
[ [0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [[6,9]], [7], [8], [[6,9]] ]
```

into this:

```
[ [0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6,9], [7], [8], [6,9] ]
```

Comment: I now suspect it's a XY problem, how do you get the first list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[item if isinstance(item, list) else [item] for items in data for item in items]
# [[0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6, 9], [7], [8], [6, 9]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
x = [i[0] if (type(i[0])==list and len(i[0])>1) else i for i in a]
```

#### Example

```
>>> a = [ [0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [[6,9]], [7], [8], [[6,9]] ]
>>> x = [i[0] if (type(i[0])==list and len(i[0])>1) else i for i in a]
>>> x
[[0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6, 9], [7], [8], [6, 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
>>> data = [ [0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [[6,9]], [7], [8], [[6,9]] ]
>>> o_data = [a[0] if isinstance(a[0], list) else a for a in data]
>>> o_data
[[0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6, 9], [7], [8], [6, 9]]
```